# Can not cast class javax.measure.unit.Unit (tec.uom.se.unit.BaseUnit and javax.measure.unit.Unit)

Tags: java, geotools

I am having an issue with the below exception being thrown, not sure how to solve it.

```
Measure distance = .....
Unit<Length> unit = distance.getUnit();

CoordinateReferenceSystem origCRS  = CRS.decode("EPSG:3785")
unit = (Unit<Length>) origCRS.getCoordinateSystem().getAxis(0).getUnit();
```

exception:

```
class tec.uom.se.unit.BaseUnit cannot be cast to class javax.measure.unit.Unit (tec.uom.se.unit.BaseUnit and javax.measure.unit.Unit are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at com.vanitysoft.canada.boundaries.domain.dao.impl.CAPostalDAOImpl.createCircleRadis(CAPostalDAOImpl.java:131)
```

the return type of .getUnit() is javax.measure.Unit so I'm not understanding why this being thrown(I don't understand the stack trace).

I'm using GeoTools 22.4

Answer (score 0):

With out seeing the actual imports you are using it's hard to be sure but GeoTools units library has changed at version 20.x and again at 24.x, see the [upgrades page](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/welcome/upgrade.html) for specific details.

In general it's wise to stay on the supported branches so I would upgrade to 24.x and try again.